# How can I check if a user is pressing a specific key i.e. Enter Key Like python's keyboard module?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I am working on making a gui chat app in java (I know too ambitious) that jus sends a message to the connected room. I have not yet done the networking stuff but jus the bare bones gui. I have a text field where the input message will be and a text area where the sent message will go with a button to send it. I want it so that when I press the enter key the sending task takes place. My code is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Jabba {
    //Class
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Main Method
        //main frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        //The Menu that will later allow us to connect and create rooms to join a chat
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu m1 = new JMenu("Connect");
        JMenu m2 = new JMenu("Help");
        //This is for help
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m2);
        JMenuItem m11 = new JMenuItem("Create new room");
        JMenuItem m22 = new JMenuItem("Join an Existing Room");
        m1.add(m11);
        m1.add(m22);

        //Our panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Text");
        //The Message field
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(15);
        //The Sending button
        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        
        
        //The resetting button
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        //Adding the panel
        panel.add(label); 
        panel.add(tf);
        panel.add(send);
        panel.add(reset);

        //The text area where the messages will go
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        //Adding it to the Scroll Pane so that It has scrolls
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
        
        //Actionlisteners allow us to listen to the actions that take place with 
        //The Specific components like here when the button is pressed
        send.addActionListener(e ->{
            //It will first store the text of the the text field in a
            //variable called msg
            String msg = tf.getText();  
            //Then Will remove the Text from the field so that new messages can be 
            //sent
            tf.setText(null);
            //Now it will send The message to the message text area
            ta.append(msg+"\n");
            });
        reset.addActionListener(e ->{
            //This is for the reset option
                ta.setText(null);
            //It will jus set all the text of the message area to null
            //i.e. Nothing
        }
        );  
        
        //adds all the content and components to the main frame.
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, mb);
        /*notice the BorderLayout here, it is from the awt package and it 
        is letting us lay the components in a specific layout. 
        Also we have changed the component below after the center to sp
        i.e. it is the scrollpane instead of our textarea to get the Scroll Bars!!*/
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, sp);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //Pretty Self-Explanatory
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltd4t.png)
Please help me and forgive me if I asked the question wrong as I couldn't quite understand how to us the KeyListener classs...## Heading ##

Comment: I would recommend attaching an `ActionListener` to the `JTextField`, possibly using the instance that the `send` button is using.  See [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

So as Mad Programmer told me and helped me I used an action Listener in that textfield and copied the code I used for the send message in an action listener for the text field var tf. So in pseudocode it is:

```
tf.addActionListener(e ->{
            String msg = tf.getText();
            tf.setText(null);
            ta.append(msg+"\n");
        });
```

Comment: Create an `Action`. Then you can add the same instance of the Action to your JTextField and your JButton. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information. Or if you are going to use a lambda, then you should create a method that can be invoked from both components so you don't repeat code.